# php и ajax работают долго

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Есть корзина товаров, работает с помощью сессии, а также php обработчик и js файл, который шлет Ajax запросы в обработчик.

Так вот, допустим у нас 10 товаров в корзине. Теперь я удаляю их по одному.

Если это делать медленно, то все пройдет успешно.

Если нажимать на крестики быстро, то могут удалиться не все товары (они не успевают) или, если удалятся все, то количестве товаров в корзине и итоговая сумма могут не обнулиться до конца.

Почему так происходит?

---

Пример Ajax запроса:

```
//Обновление виджета корзины в шапке
function updateCart() {
    $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', {
        action: 'updateCart'
    },
        function (res) {
            $('.cart-btn').html(res);
        }
    );
}
updateCart();
```

Пример PHP обработчика:

```
function updateCart(){

    $data = json_decode(stripslashes($_SESSION['cart']), ARRAY_A);

    // Перебераю массив
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        // Узнаю общее количество товара
        $quantity_product += $value;

        // Узнаю цену и умножаю на колличество
        $price_product += get_field('price', $key) * $value;
    }


    // Вывожу колличество товара и сумму
    if(!$data){
        echo "Товаров 0 (0) тг.";
    } else {
        if($quantity_product == 1) {
            echo "$quantity_product товар ($price_product) тг.";
        } elseif($quantity_product > 1) {
            echo "Товаров: $quantity_product ($price_product) тг.";
        }
    }

    die();
}
```

Comment: А где запись переменной сессии?

Comment: Хотя, как я понял, это бессмысленный код. При аякс запросе пересчет количесва товаров и сумму надо делать на клиенте средствами js после успешного ответа сервера о выполнении операции по удалению товара.

Answer (score 0):

Ответы на множественные запросы не обязательно придут в том порядке, в котором отправлены.

Проще всего запретить новый запрос, пока не отработан предыдущий, хотя это далеко не самое лучшее решение. Например, так:

```
var isWaiting;
//Обновление виджета корзины в шапке
function updateCart() {
    if (isWaiting) { return; }
    isWaiting = true;
    $.post('/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        {
            action: 'updateCart'
        },
        function (res) {
            //Очистить флаг ожидания после успешного выполнения запроса
            isWaiting = false;
            $('.cart-btn').html(res);
        }
    ).fail(function(res) {
        //Очистить флаг ожидания при ошибке запроса
        isWaiting = false;
    });
}
updateCart();
```

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Для того кода, который приведен, причина ошибок названа правильно. И это правильное решение, хоть и в лоб. Можете предложить лучшее именно для этого кода - вперед, предлагайте.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов Ваш подход к решению проблемы- правильный. Мой, для данного случая - не очень. Моё решение более применимо, когда мы не хотим выполнять некий запрос, пока другой, такой же не завершён. Только вот дискуссию Вы ведёте некрасиво.

Comment: Почему бы не использовать обёртку $.ajax с параметром async:false?